# Subquery returning True/False instead of actual value

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select 
orders.id "Order ID",
markets.name "Market",
organizations.name "Organization Name",
order_cancellations.reason "Cancellation Reason",
users.name "Cancelled by",
orders.service_level "Service Level",
orders.needed_vehicle_type "Vehicle Type",
order_cancellations.comment "Comment",
dpoc.driver_compensation = (select 
dopc.driver_compensation
from analytics.fire_order_price_calculations dopc
where calculation_type = 'inital_estimate' 
 ) "Starting Driver Fare"
from analytics.fire_orders as orders
inner join analytics.fire_order_price_calculations as dpoc on orders.id = dpoc.order_id
```

The above query is a portion of the full query I am working with. I am having problem at the section below:

```
dpoc.driver_compensation = (select 
dopc.driver_compensation
from analytics.fire_order_price_calculations dopc
where calculation_type = 'inital_estimate' 
 ) "Starting Driver Fare"
```

I am trying to return the prices for the calculation type inital_estimate, however the return rows for the column are true/false and I want the return rows be the actual values

Comment: Boolean expression, `dpoc.driver_compensation = (select `, returns true/false/null.

Comment: @jarlh when I remove it I get "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" error

Comment: You probably need a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3):

remove the equality symbol so that the sub-query is treated as a column

```
SELECT
      orders.id "Order ID"
    , markets.name "Market"
    , organizations.name "Organization Name"
    , order_cancellations.reason "Cancellation Reason"
    , users.name "Cancelled by"
    , orders.service_level "Service Level"
    , orders.needed_vehicle_type "Vehicle Type"
    , order_cancellations.comment "Comment"
    , dpoc.driver_compensation
    , (
        SELECT dopc.driver_compensation
        FROM analytics.fire_order_price_calculations dopc
        WHERE calculation_type = 'inital_estimate'
        ) "Starting Driver Fare"
FROM analytics.fire_orders AS orders
INNER JOIN analytics.fire_order_price_calculations AS dpoc ON orders.id = dpoc.order_id
```

**However** there is no "correlation" from the outer query into the subquery so the subquery can return many rows and that will fail.

Try a case expression instead, perhaps this will address the wanted conditions:

```
SELECT
      orders.id "Order ID"
    , markets.name "Market"
    , organizations.name "Organization Name"
    , order_cancellations.reason "Cancellation Reason"
    , users.name "Cancelled by"
    , orders.service_level "Service Level"
    , orders.needed_vehicle_type "Vehicle Type"
    , order_cancellations.comment "Comment"
    , dpoc.driver_compensation 
    ,  case when dpoc.calculation_type = 'inital_estimate' 
              then dpoc.driver_compensation
       end as "Starting Driver Fare"
FROM analytics.fire_orders AS orders
INNER JOIN analytics.fire_order_price_calculations AS dpoc ON orders.id = dpoc.order_id
```

Comment: I get an error ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: My response wasn't complete, try the case expression. If this still does not work please supply sample data (for each table separately)  and the expected result.